# Updating a Query and Form based on a table

Tags: sql, vba

I have two questions both related - I have a table with column headings - based on this table is a query and a form. If I add another column heading to my table how do I get the query and the form to update and show the new table column heading - I have some VBA knowledge but not enough to work this out - thanks Dave

Comment: An Excel table?  A table in a database (what kind of database)?  There's too little context in your question to provide useful suggestions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am using Access 2016

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned sql and forms. Are you utilizing MS Access?

If you are, you will need to add the new field in the sql query, then add the new field into the form.

Not knowing what you are working with or examples of how it is laid out limits what help I can offer.

Comment: I have a table that contains Raw Material Prices- there is a query based on this table and then a form based on the query. on the form, I have code which is run by an event procedure that asks the user what new name to enter into the Raw Material Prices     table this enters a new column/field which then needs to be shown in the query and form - thanks

Comment: Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()

Dim strDdl As String
  
    Invno = InputBox("Please Enter the New Raw Material", "ENTER NEW RAW MATERIAL", 1)
   strDdl = "ALTER TABLE tblCoating ADD COLUMN " & Invno & " TEXT(255);"
   CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDdl
     
    
End Sub

Comment: Sorry guys in the code it should read tblRawMaterialPrices and not tblCoating

Comment: My question is similar to Adding data fields from the table to form automatically using vba. This was answered just over 4 years ago -and confirms that the Form must be opened in Design View to make changes - so it looks like I must rethink my strategy unless another way has been discovered since the question was asked last time. thanks Dave

Comment: Still not sure if I follow, but you could utilize a secondary (sub) table to list "Raw Materials" and "Prices". That way each choice becomes a new record in the table. A form then can utilize a combo box to limit choices to that table. Adding a new material is as simple as adding a record.

Comment: Hi Clint - thanks for taking the trouble to reply.If I can try and explain what I am trying to achieve. I have 445 recipes that include any one or more of the fields on the Raw Material Prices table. The Raw Material Prices table first field is the ingredient name the second field is the field which has the same name at the ingdient name field - I have 54 separate prices and each raw material has ist own line and its own field/column- I do this so when I have a form it shows a name and price box for each ingredient.Firstly is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have 445 recipes from which you are making a database. I assume that form is used to create the record for each recipe. On the form are fields that need to reference each ingredient's name and price. To achieve this you have created a second table that contains the name and price of the various 54 ingredients? Each ingredient has a record on this table as well as a field with the same name?

Comment: Yes, you are correct - I do not nake a separate recipe form for each product. The form has a Combo box that selects each recipe. On this form is added all the ingredients for each recipe the Raw Material prices table is also placed onto this form . Then I make the calculations by selecting the ingredient and price multiplied by the kilos of each ingredient used in that particular recipe. This now brings me to wanting to enter a new Raw Material price onto the table and getting it to flow through the form.